# Mime Types in the Windows registry

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mime-types

In my windows service built with C# I am trying to set the mime types based on the file extensions as shown below

```
static string GetMimeType(string fileName)
{
    string mimeType = "application/unknown";
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();

    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
   
    if (regKey != null && regKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
        mimeType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
    
    return mimeType;
}
```

On the production server we don't have Acrobat or word installed for obvious reasons.
How do I get around with this? Is there any other way of setting the mime types?
If not how do I create those mime types on the production server without having to install those softwares.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14):

You can simply create the registry entries for those types for your code to read

- in regedit go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` (the central part of `HKCR`)
- right click `Classes`, *New Key* - call it `.pdf`
- right click on the right hand side, *New String* - `Content Type`, `application/pdf`

or you can find a machine that does have Acrobat installed and then use regedit to export the `.pdf` key to a registry script you can import on your server. You'll end up with lots of scripts: you can use notepad to edit them together but make sure you don't change the encoding when you save - it has to be Unicode!

You could equally add a list of mappings into your application but IIS won't serve static content when it doesn't have a content type so you should probably add them to your registry too in case you ever need to serve static PDFs.