# Show video file in listview keep download option in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

My concept is about stegnography. I want to play the video file and keep the download option. If the client clicks the download button, the video along with registration message should download.

I used the following code

in .cs

```
 DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath("~/Video"));
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    ArrayList listItems = new ArrayList();
    foreach (FileInfo info in files)
    {
        listItems.Add(info);
    }
    DataList1.DataSource = listItems;
    DataList1.DataBind();
```

in design

```
        Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Small" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"

        Width="600px" ForeColor="#333333">                
                <ItemTemplate>                

            <br />          
            <b>Song Name:</b>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
          <video controls="controls"  width="200" height="200" src='<%# Eval ("name","Video/{0}") %>'></video>
            <br />
            <b>Download:</b>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

here download option is not working, can any 1 give some idea for this plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best[*] way to download a big file, like a video, is to use a handler.

So you create a handler that send the file and you send the parametres of what file to download on the url. For example you can do something like:

```
 <b>Download:</b> <a target="_blank" href="download.ashx?name=<%#Eval("name") %>'>"><%#Eval("name") %>'></a>
```

And on the handler `download.ashx` you read the parameter "name" and you send that file.

This also can help you:
[What is the best way to download file from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912164/what-is-the-best-way-to-download-file-from-server/10912955#10912955)
[asp.net ashx handler prompting download instead of displaying file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452125/asp-net-ashx-handler-prompting-download-instead-of-displaying-file)
[files download using HTTP Handler](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544289/Restricting-files-download-using-HTTP-Handler-base)

[*]Why is the best way to use a hander ?:

1. Have the minimum of code compare with an aspx page.
2. Have clear return - Send only what you render on output.
3. Did not use session, so did not felt into the [session lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426673/web-app-blocked-while-processing-another-web-app-on-sharing-same-session/9427550#9427550) and you avoid time outs

Comment: thanks for ur reply, but can you provide me code for download.aspx

Comment: this asp.net ashx handler prompting download instead of displaying file, this file I used, but showing error in filename, which is not mentioned

Comment: @user3856392 you have write `give some idea for this plz` and thats I did. I can not predict what exactly you try to do, and I do not understand whats your issue.